# C++ code behaves differently in Release on XCode 12

Tags: ios, xcode, poco-libraries

My app is using third-party lib which is in turn built on Poco library. The poco library is included as compiled object file (.a). Now app works as expected in the debug mode but brings a failure in release mode.

I was able to track it down to that line. The string as input is identical in both modes but in release mode empty object is returned (no exception, just object with the size 0).

```
    Poco::JSON::Parser parser;
    try {
        *object = parser.parse(jsonstr);
    }
```

The thing started when we switched to XCode 12 for app and for the Poco compilation.

My take is that it should be some optimization flags plus bug in the library but how should I track it down? Especially with no debugging in release mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you break out the `parse` and `extract` calls.  There might be some implicit conversion messing you up.

Comment: `Var result = parser.parse(json);`

`Object::Ptr object = result.extract<Object::Ptr>();`